# Basic MySQL project: defining keys and on delete cascades

Tags: mysql

I am a beginning student in MYSQL and I have the following assignment:

Create a database with the name UNIVERSITY. Then create tables in UNIVERSITY according to the following schemas:

- Student(**Sid**; Sname;GPA)
- MajorsIn(**Sid**;Major)
- Book(**BookNo**; Title; Price)
- Cites(**BookNo**;**CitedBookNo**)
- Buys(**Sid**;**BookNo**)

A student can have multiple Majors or no major.  A tuple (b,c) in the relation
Cites indicates that the book with book number b cites the book with book number c.

Where appropriate, add “ON DELETE CASCADE” statements with the foreign key
constraints.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE DATABASE University;
CREATE TABLE Stu ( sid INTEGER, 
    gpa REAL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (sid) ) 
CREATE TABLE Majorsin ( sid INTEGER, 
     Major CHAR(10),   
     PRIMARY KEY (sid) ) 
CREATE TABLE Book ( bookno INTEGER, 
     title CHAR(10), 
     price REAL,   
CREATE TABLE Cites ( bookno INTEGER, 
     citedbookno INTEGER,   
CREATE TABLE Buys ( sid INTEGER, 
     bookno INTEGER,   
     PRIMARY KEY (sid) )
```

My question is: what changes to the above code do I need to make to meet the requirements?  In particular, what changes do I need to make in terms of defining the keys and where do i need to put "ON DELETE CASCADES?'

Sorry if this is a basic/general question: I'm a noob and could use some help getting through this first assignment.

Thanks!

Comment: You're taking a class on this subject. Didn't they explain it in the lecture, or in the textbook?

Comment: The `Book` and `Cites` table creation queries seem to be cut off in the middle.

Comment: In any table that contains a column that refers to the key in some other table, you add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint with the `ON DELETE CASCADES` option, for instance `sid` in `Buys` refers to `sid` in `Stu`.

Comment: @Barmar Not really.  It is an 'on-ramp,' and the level of instruction is extremely light.  Basically a few powerpoint presentations that don't go into enough detail for a novice like me.

Comment: Then I guess you need to go looking for tutorials on the Internet. SO is not a programming school.